# pip fails to install numpy error code 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pip

I'm trying to install numpy using pip. When I type `pip install numpy` in the command prompt it goes to work but won't install the file and returns an error code `1`. I am using windows 8 64-Bit and python 2.7.This is the final bit of the error message

```
Cleaning up...

Removing temporary dir c:\users\pim\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Pim...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\pim\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Pim\numpy

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 236, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1134, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 259, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\util.py", line 670, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\pim\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Pim\numpy
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Installing extension modules can be an issue with pip.  This is why conda exists.  conda is an open-source BSD-licensed cross-platform package manager.  It can easily install NumPy.

Two options:

- Install [Anaconda](http://www.continuum.io/downloads)
- Install [Miniconda](http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/index.html) and then go to a command-line and type `conda install numpy` (make sure your PATH includes the location conda was installed to).

Answer (score 1):

I would guess this is due to pip 1.3 has a bug dealing with ssl. There is a link [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/aSlPCNYcVjw).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have python-dev installed (as you'll definitely see this same error if you don't).

```
dpkg -l python-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Some File can not be installed with pip and need to be installed from your platform’s packages.

So You guys can try this if nth work up there 
**MAC** 
With Macports

```
sudo port install 'package'
```

With Homebrew:

```
brew install 'Package'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using python 3+ try to install with pip3

```
    pip3 install numpy
```

another thing (windows) make sure you have the latest version of Microsoft Visual C++

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded python 37, and I customized install location. Then I tried to install numpy using pip: failed error code 1.
Then I deleted python 37, downloaded python 36 without customizing install location. Then I installed numpy using pip: successful.
Perhaps customizing install location caused the error.